# is a given expression an irreducible fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The following statement is pretty obvious:

```
For six integers a, b, c, A, B, C

if 

    the six integers are pairwise co-prime, and
    the absolute value of each is greater than 1

then

    a/A is an irreducible fraction
    b/B is an irreducible fraction
    c/C is an irreducible fraction
    (a/A)*(b/B)*(c/C) is an irreducible fraction
```

But what about this product:

```
    (1 - a/A)*(1 - b/B)*(1 - c/C)
```

Is this product always an irreducible fraction?

In other words, can the product never be an integer?

If the product can never be an integer, how do I prove it?

Does it make any difference if A,B,C are squares?

Comment: $(1 - a/A),(1 - b/B),(1 - c/C)$ are all irreducible fractions.

Answer (score 1):

The product can be an integer. Take $(a,b,c,A,B,C)=(3,11,37,5,7,2)$. Note these are pairwise coprime (indeed they are each in fact prime).

Then

$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{a}{A}\right)\left(1-\frac{b}{B}\right)\left(1-\frac{c}{C}\right)
&=\left(1-\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(1-\frac{11}{7}\right)\left(1-\frac{37}{2}\right)
\\&=\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)\left(\frac{-4}{7}\right)\left(\frac{-35}{2}\right)
\\&=4
\end{align}$$

The idea is that while $a,b,c,A,B,C$ may be pairwise coprime, it does not follow that $A-a,B-b,C-c,A,B,C$ are pairwise coprime (Note that $1-\dfrac{x}{X}=\dfrac{X-x}{X}$).

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the product can be written as $\displaystyle\frac{(A-a)(B-b)(C-c)}{ABC}$:

- The product is not always an irreducible fraction: for example, if $A, a, B, b, C, c$ are equal to $5, 3, 2, 17, 13, 11$, respectively, then $A-a=2$ or $C-c=2$ in the numerator can be simplified with $B=2$ in the denominator.
- The product can be an integer: for example, if $A, a, B, b, C, c$ are equal to $3, 7, 5, 13, 4, 19$, we have $\displaystyle\frac{(3-7)(5-13)(4-19)}{3\cdot5\cdot4}=-8$.
- If $A, B, C$ are squares, the product can still be an integer: for example, if $A, a, B, b, C, c$ are equal to $9, 19, 25, 41, 16, 61$, we have $\displaystyle\frac{(9-19)(25-41)(16-61)}{9\cdot25\cdot16}=-2$.

Comment: Your counterexample for general A,B,C has me convinced, but your counterexample for A^2, B^2, C^2 does not work because you mistakenly made a, b, c square in the numerator, but you should have made A, B, C square in the numerator.  When I make the correct substitutions, I get a product of -1/50, which is clearly not an integer.  The squares question is really the one that I'm actually interested in.  Nevertheless, I sincerely thank you for your interest.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I interpreted the question as if you were interested in finding a product of the form $(1-a/A^2)(1-b/B^2)(1-c/C^2)$ giving an integer result. Using the numbers $A^2=9$,$B^2=25$, $C^2=16$, and $a=49$,$b=169$, $c=361$, the result is an integer (the fact that $a,b,c$ are also squares is only by simplicity, but should not be relevant for the question). However, it is possible that your interest in the question was different from that I interpreted. Could you provide some additional details to better explain? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer with another example where $A, B, C$ are squares and $a,b,c$ are not square.

Comment: Your new answer with (A,a,B,b,C,c) = (9,19,25,41,16,61) makes the correct substitutions for A,B,C as squares.  I needed to interpret this as (A,a,B,b,C,c) = 3,19,5,41,4,61), because I was squaring A,B and C.  Anyway your counterexample works perfectly and produces -2 as the result.  --O.C.Riley